# Position of a figure within columns

Tags: tikz-pgf

The code does not place the last picture (Bunny 3) and its label directly below the second picture (Bunny 2). The picture of Bunny 3 and its label are shifted. How can I do that? Thank you!

```
\documentclass[9pt,handout,compress,rgb]{beamer}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

{\bf Contributors}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]
    \node[circle,draw=none, label={below:{\newline\bf Bunny 1}}, fill overzoom image={figures/bunny.png},inner sep=1cm] at (0,0) {};
    \node[circle,draw=none, label={below:{\newline\bf Bunny 2}}, fill overzoom image={figures/bunny.png},inner sep=1cm] at (13,0) {};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{columns}

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\bluebf{The research was very important.}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]

    \node[circle,draw=none, label={below:{\newline\bf Bunny 3}}, fill overzoom image={figures/bunny.png},inner sep=1cm] at (13,0) {};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{column}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Some notes: `scale` doesn't do much when it's not applied as an option to a node or if `transform shape` isn't set. The `at (13,0)` only specifies the position in relation to other stuff inside the `tikzpicture` not in relation to the page or the line. (Change it or leave it out in your last picture to see that.) Also [Q516](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516).

Comment: If you want them to line up, use three tikzpictures (or just \includegraphics) and put all of them into columns.

Answer (score 1):

if you want aligned figures, you can use a similar `columns` structure for both lines:

```
\documentclass[9pt,handout,compress,rgb]{beamer}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

{\bf Contributors}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]
    \node[circle,draw=none, label={below:{\newline\bf Bunny 1}}, fill overzoom image={example-image-a},inner sep=1cm] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]
    \node[circle,draw=none, label={below:{\newline\bf Bunny 2}}, fill overzoom image={example-image-b},inner sep=1cm] at (13,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\textbf{The research was very important.}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]
    \node[circle,draw=none, label={below:{\newline\bf Bunny 3}}, fill overzoom image={example-image-c},inner sep=1cm] at (13,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using columns, you can align all elements in a single `tikzpicture` using the library `positioning`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[9pt,handout,compress,rgb]{beamer}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}% added <<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}% added <<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{graphicx}% added <<<<<<<<<<<
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
                \node(a)[circle,draw=none, label={below:{\newline\bfseries Bunny 1}}, fill overzoom image={example-image-a}, inner sep=1cm] {};
                \node(b)[circle,draw=none, label={below:{\newline\bfseries Bunny 2}}, fill overzoom image={example-image-b}, inner sep=1cm, right = of a]  {};
                \node(c)[circle,draw=none, label={below:{\newline\bfseries Bunny 3}}, fill overzoom image={example-image-c}, inner sep=1cm, below = of b] {};               
                \node(x)[font=\bfseries, text=black,above left= of a] {Contributors};%
                \node[font=\bfseries, text=blue, anchor= west] at (x.west|-c.center)  {The research was very important.};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
        
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```